# Why data is entered in the database if the string length is greater than the set maximum

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a login system but i don't know why the data is entered in the database if the string length is greater than the set varchar maximum. I set the varchar(20) in database and when i register a new account and I type the string of username more than 20 characters the first 20 characters are inserted.

Specifically, the accountOption.php file is out of the root document, the connection works

this is the action function:

```
    function registerAccount($username,$password,$email){
     global $db;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,email) VALUES (:username,:password,:email)"; 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username,':password'=>$password,':email'=>$email));
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

           $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = $username;
    header("Location: ?page=loggedIn&message=Registered");

    }else {
         header("Location: ?page=register&message=Failed");
    }



}
```

and this is the form.php

```
        <?php 
if(isset($_GET['message'])){
    echo $_GET['message']."<br>";
}
?>
Please register:
<form action="?bpage=accountOptions&action=register&nonUI" method="post">

    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email"><br>  
    <br>
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

The connection.php

```
<?php 

    global $db;

            $userdb="yyy";
            $passworddb="xxx";


    try {
        $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;',$userdb,$passworddb);

    }catch(Exception $ex){

        throw new Exception("Nu am reusit sa ne conectam la db");
    }


?>
```

Comment: That's just how MySQL works by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL will insert characters up to the column's maximum length unless [strict SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) is enabled. From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html):

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a CHAR or VARCHAR column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is truncated to fit and a warning is generated. For truncation of nonspace characters, you can cause an error to occur (rather than a warning) and suppress insertion of the value by using strict SQL mode. See Section 5.1.8, “Server SQL Modes”.

If you want the database to enforce this maximum length, you'll need to enable strict SQL mode. Otherwise (or also), you'll need to validate the length in your application.

Keep in mind that if you *do* enable strict SQL mode, there will be other potential effects, because it's... strict.